# How to set value to the child map in the father map in kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, multidimensional-array, mutablemap

as title, I have the code:

```kotlin
val description= mutableMapOf(
    "father2" to "123",
    "father" to mutableMapOf<String,String>())
description["father"]["child"] = "child value"
```

if i try this: `description["father"]["child"]="child value"`

I will get the error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<String!, String!>.set(key: String!, value: String!): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline operator fun kotlin.text.StringBuilder /* = java.lang.StringBuilder */.set(index: Int, value: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.text
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about typing (or lack of it).

The `description` map is created from two pairs, one from a `String` to a `String`, and the other from a `String` to a `MutableMap<String, String>`.  The keys are both `String`, so Kotlin will infer `String` for the type of key.  But what about the values?  They're two completely unrelated types, with no common superclass except `Any`.  So **the type of `description` is inferred to be `MutableMap<String, Any>`**.  (You can check that in e.g. the REPL.)

So, when you pull out a value, what can the compiler tell about it?  Almost nothing.  It's an `Any`, so the only thing you can be sure of is that it's not null.

That's why **the compiler isn't treating that pulled-out value like a map; as far as it knows, it might not *be* a map**!  (*We* know — but only because we can see what the map was initialised with, and that it's not modified since then, nor is the reference shared with any other objects or threads that could modify it.  But that's a relatively rare circumstance.)

Kotlin is a strongly-typed language, which means the compiler tracks the type of everything, and tries very hard not to let you do anything that could cause a runtime error.  Your code, if it compiled, would risk a `ClassCastException` any time the data didn't exactly match what you expected, which is hardly a route to good programs.

So, what can you do?

The safest thing would be to **change your program so that you don't *have* any maps with unknown types of values**.  Obviously, that depends on what your program is doing, so we can't make useful suggestions here.  But if your `description` were a `MutableMap<String, MutableMap<String, String>>`, then the compiler would know exactly what type everything was, and your intended code would compile and run fine.

The other main alternative would be to ***check* what the value is before trying to treat it like a map**.  One way to do this uses the `as?` safe-cast operator.  That checks whether a value is of a given type; if so, it's cast to that type; otherwise, it returns null.  You can then use the `.?` safe-call operator to call a method only if the value isn't null.  Putting that together:

```
(description["father"] as? MutableMap<String, String>)?.put("child", "child value")
```

If the value is as you expect, that will work fine; if not, it will do nothing and continue.

That's rather long-winded, but it will compile and run safely.  Alternatively, you could do the same thing in a more explicit way like this:

```
val child = description["father"]
if (child is MutableMap<String, String>))
    child["child"] = "child value"
```

(Within the `if`, the compiler knows the type of `child`, and uses a a ‘smart cast’ to allow the putter call.)

That's even more long-winded, of course.  But that's what you get from trying to work against the type system :-)

(Oh, and by the way, I think the usual terminology for recursive data structures is ‘parent’ and ‘child’; I've not seen ‘father’ used that way before.)

Comment: This strong type conversion is exactly what I am looking for. I didn't expect the answer to be `as?`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
description["father"]?.put("child", "child value")
```

Comment: in the jetbrains's IDE, will throw `Unresolved reference: put`, but kotlin Playground can run it.

Comment: and then it suggested me `Create extension function 'Any?.put'`, but only solved the red bottom line, `description["father"]` still is empty

Comment: Sorry, this is because I initialized to Any in `description` and I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

My current solution:

```
val description:MutableMap<String,Any> = mutableMapOf(
    "father" to "123"
)

val father2 = mutableMapOf<String,String>()
father2.put("child", "child value")
description["father2"]=father2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
val description = mutableMapOf<String?,MutableMap<String,String>?> 
("father" to mutableMapOf<String,String>())

description.get("father")?.put("Key","Value")
println(description) // {father={Key=Value}}
```